# vue-cli-service build: validationError for new workbox-webpack-plugin options

Tags: vue.js, webpack, workbox, vue-cli-3, workbox-webpack-plugin

With the following vue.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  pwa: { 
    name: 'My App',
    ...
    workboxPluginMode: 'InjectManifest',
    workboxOptions: {
      swSrc: 'src/sw.js', //and I use "sw.js" in my registerServiceWorker.js file
      skipWaiting: true,
      clientsClaim: true,
    }
  }
}
```

The validation errors during build are that 'skipWaiting' and 'clientsClaim' are not supported parameters. Why? swSrc is from the same list of options listed [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-webpack-plugin) and the build doesn't complain about that option. When I remove these two options, the build works.

So I guess my question is:

`skipWaiting`, `clientsClaim` are "not a supported parameter" of **what**? Of webpack? of the PWA plugin? Of the workbox-webpack plugin? Where can I find the correct set of options? Thanks.

UPDATE: I do not have a .env file setting the NODE-ENV. However `npm run build` which I guess builds production assets works *only if I remove the 2 options*. The removed options in dev (`npm run serve`) yields NO service worker file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using workbox plugin in `InjectManifest` mode, but pass parameters for `GenerateSW`.

`InjectManifest` mode expects an existing service-worker file to be injected and it's path defined in `swSrc`, while `GenerateSW` will create service-worker file, thus accepts different set of options (e.g. `swDest`, etc)

All options for each of modes can be found on the same documentation page of [workbox-webpack-plugin](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-webpack-plugin) you've posted in corresponding sections.

Comment: OK so based on that, I've now included importScripts() for the workbox-sw.js from CDN. I thought vue would do that for me. I just have a console.log in my worker for now - will look at the link u sent for more complex stuff later. The registration now fails with `Service worker not found at /sw.js` so the file is still not being generated :(

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer anyway bcos it explains the validationError!

Comment: Thank you. Check if it was generated at all. Because, if `swDest` was not specified, default output will be `service-worker.js`.